# djb2 by Dan Bernstein for c++

Tags: c++, hash, hash-function

I've tried to translate djb2 hash function from c-code

```
unsigned long
hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

to c++ code, but i have segmentation fault.

```
int hf(std::string s){
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    char c;
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        c=s[i++];
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash;
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `s[i]`, not `s[i++]`. Even better would be to use range-based for.

```
int hf(std::string const& s) {
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    for (auto c : s) {
        hash = (hash << 5) + hash + c; /* hash * 33 + c */
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: I have warning warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

Comment: Use `-std=c++11`. If for whatever reason you can’t use C++11, just use your original code but with `s[i]` instead of `s[i++]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain it in more detail, where i need to use it? I use Sublime Text for compiling and running programms.

Comment: I've changed s[i++] to s[i] and still have segmentation fault.

Comment: In that case the problem must lie elsewhere. Is your string very long? If so, use `std::size_t` instead of `int` as the data type of `i`.

Comment: also implicit conversion of return-value from `unsigned long` to `int`

Comment: None of these (neither the surplus increment nor the conversion) are a reason for crash, but they will/may cause incorrect hash values. Both the original and rightfold's much improved version must work -- error is likely elsewhere. Calling function with null string object maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one I made that is pretty fast and c++ friendly.

```
unsigned long DJB2hash(string str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    unsigned int size  = str.length();
    unsigned int i     = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + (str[i]); /* hash * 33 + c */
    }

    return hash;
}
```